# Safari Flash WMODE not working - anything wrong with this embed?

Tags: flash, safari, wmode

I've got a problem with this embed in Safari. It works just fine on all other browsers, Internet Explorer 6 included. The problem is that the embed seems to jump to the very top layer, ignoring all z-index or positioning statements. This is important, because several HTML design features are overlayed on the Flash.

This embed was written to work with [SWFobject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWFObject), but still doesn't work when:

1. swfobject disabled
2. wmode = transparent/opaque/removed entirely

Is this a problem with Safari or the code? And if it's the code then what does Safari do differently to all the other browsers?

```
<object id="Flash_Banner" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="950" height="400" title="">
    <param name="movie" value="ui.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="ui.swf" width="950" height="400" title="">
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <div id="banner_slider"><img src="images/banners/case.jpg" width="950" height="400" alt="" /></div>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Comment: Similar to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105908/safari-windows-and-transparent-flash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the same thing with Safari for Windows and it works fine on Safari for Mac. So it may be a bug in Safari for Windows.

Comment: Latest safari install has corrected the error - seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a link to an example page of what you are trying to accomplish?

I have set up a demo using your code and a bit of content here: http://demo.raleighbuckner.com/so/1270978/

Not knowing how your other content is set up, I chose to put the flash element in a <div> and the content in a separate <div>. The flash container is absolutely positioned to pull it out of the page flow and allow the content to move over it.

I also added another test to the page with the wmode set to "transparent".

Here's what I see in IE7, FF3 and Safari 4 with Flash Player 10:

- Both content areas appear above the flash.
- The top flash does not let the page background show through.
- The bottom flash lets the page background show through.

If you see the same, then there is most likely something else in your HTML that is throwing things off. Post a link to your page and I'll see what I can figure out.

If you do not see the same, then there could be something borked with your Safari and/or Flash Player.

Comment: Latest safari install has corrected the error - seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will happen after upgrading your browser or flash player. In safari the
`wmode = "transparent"` will not let you insert any text in the input field. You have to keep the `wmode = "window/opaque"`. There is no other solutions.

My safari version is 5.1 and flash 11.2.202.333.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug on safari on windows. I tried safari on Mac 3.0-4.0.4 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Flash player 10.0.45.2 there is a z-index bug with the Windows version of Safari for previous versions of the Flash player.